# Como imprimir una fila y columna específica en UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

me podrán ayudar a imprimir el elemento 2x2 de este fichero.txt

```
 #diametro,modulo de young,error,errorpendiente,intercepto
 1   733.650208      0.132335603      0.381077677
```

Necesito obtener el elemento 2x2, es decir 733.650208. Lo estaba intentando con este comando:

```
 ls -l | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

pero no me funciona porque me arroja este resultado

```
de
733.650208
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un sólo comando, utilizando `awk`.

```
$ awk 'NR == 2 {print $2}' archivo
```

Lo cual hace en esencia lo siguiente "Si el número de línea es 2, entonces imprime el segundo campo separado por espacios". `NR` es una variable que contiene el número de línea que se está procesando.

Un problema que veo es que haces uso del comando `ls`, el cual es exclusivo para mostrar los metadatos de un árbol de archivos, entonces no entiendo si es de un archivo o del contenido de un directorio. Si es de un archivo común, el comando de arriba te funciona.

Si quieres usar la respuesta de @Jakala, esta se puede reducir a un simple tail, y el head sale sobrando.

```
$ tail -n +2 archivo | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Es de un archivo, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar sed para seleccionar la fila y dejas el comando del awk para seleccionar la columna

```
sed '2q;d' fichero.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion, seria:

1.- leer el numero de lineas del archivo (en este caso 2) con head

2.- cojer la ultima linea con tail

3.- cortar el elemento que deseas (en este caso el elemento 2)

la linea seria la siguiente:

```
head -n2 fichero.txt | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Con modificar el -n2 de head (para fila) y el $2 para columna, podrias seleccionar la columna deseada. Por ej, para el elemento 4x3 seria:

```
head -n4 fichero.txt | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: Gracias, quiero utilizarlo con el comando exec pero me arroja error con su respuesta  `find ./K'0'$a/ -name 'fichero.txt' -exec head -n2 fichero.txt | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $2 }' {} \; ` me explico, con el comando find ingreso a diversas carpetas con nombre K0.1,K0.2 ... K0.100 y encuentro el archivo fichero.txt, con exec quiero ejecutar su comando pero me sale error ... no estoy seguro si con exec puedo ejecutar varias comandos `head, tail, awk` a la vez porque con un comando `awk` me funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
cat fichero | cut -d " " -f1,2
cat fichero | cut -d " " -f1-3
```

Donde `-f` le pasas la posicion que deses ya que lo estas diviendo por columnas a partir de espacios